# How can I proper incorporate dynamic elements in a Horizontal Layout Group?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, layout

I am about 4 hours into debugging this, time to ask!

I have this nest of objects:

```
- Game Object
|--- Canvas
|  |---Panel
|  |  |---Element 1
|  |  |---Element 2
```

With my current configuration, Elements 1 and 2 are showing up separate with one completely off screen, rather than evenly spaced out next to one another within the specified space. It is a Horizontal Layout Group specified to:

Child Alignment: Middle Center
Child Controls Size & Force Expand: None.

The Canvas is set to Screen Space - Camera, with my only camera specified.
Those settings are here as well:

[image]

The Panel is a Rect Transform set to around the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Those settings - The panel has the Horizontal Layout Group component on it.

Next are the child objects, those settings are here:

[image]

In terms of what I have done, here are just a few:

- Tried to remove the Canvas components from the children
- Unpacked the prefabs completely to make further edits.
- Rebuild the children
- Tried Render mode of the Canvas to World Space
- Tinkered with the anchor points to see if positioning was an issue

Hierarchy is here for clarity:

[image]

This ultimately leads to this result, the graphic on the right should be in view (on the yellow screen).

Thank you in advance!
[image: Actual output]

EDIT: With Horizontal Layout Group and the rest of the object it is on: [image]

Comment: `720` as width for the child seems a bit too large (== the width of the canvas thus the offset) ... it looks quite quadratic so it should be close to `128` maybe even a bit less. since due to the text it looks actually more high then wide. Otherwise: Please also add the settings of `HorizontalLayoutgroup`

Comment: Btw you should not nest multible `Canvas` there .. since the parent is already a `Canvas` this is not needed and you could use only a simply gameObject with a RectTransform as the root object for that `NextAchievement`.

Comment: As derHugo mentioned - Canvsas component in the middle of the layout setup will break layout (will slice it at points where you added canvas). Start with one canvas and work up from there. RectTransform is a tricky beast at first but its worth learning it deeply (4hrs is nothing)

Comment: also, please post screenshot of your layoutgrop setup - checkboxes that set what controls what are crucial

Comment: Thank you for the ideas so far. When I was in Scene mode, changing the width from 720 helped there, as soon as they spawned in game though they reverted back to the above. I've attached the settings for the game object above!